# Is the ISP allocation of public IP addresses below valid or invalid

Tags: subnet, ipv4

If my ISP is giving me a public IP address block of (for example) 89.45.40.0/24, then for the internet to function properly, it is important that nobody has already assigned a block like the following one to another party 89.45.0.0/16

Is the above statement correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the above statement is incorrect.

For example, suppose a registry assigned 89.0.0.0/8 to a party who assigned 89.45.0.0/16 to another party. This is precisely what you're saying can't be allowed for the Internet to function properly.

But suppose that party assigned 89.45.0.0/17 to your ISP who assigned 89.45.40.0/24 to you? How could that possibly be a problem?

Comment: I agree. Let me rephrase the question. Suppose all assignments are non-transferrable and are being made to the final user (eg. a corporations, not to ISPs who can further sub-divide the ranges they are assigned). Then would my original statement be correct then?

Comment: @snaik I can still imagine edge cases where it would be fine. For example, say the assignment was for a purely private IP network that had nothing to do with the Internet.

Comment: "where it would be fine" = "my original statement would be correct"?

Comment: No, I mean your statement would be incorrect and the allocation would cause no problems.